# Upload image from entire phone

Tags: java, android, image, android-layout, android-activity

I have created an activity that upon button click user are able to upload a picture from their device gallery, which would get cast to an imageview. The problem is that it is only able to retrieve image from device gallery, not from phone camera gallery, or from phone google drive folder. I would want that its able to upload any picture from their phone, regardless of the source.

Below is the code:

```
    Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
    });

} 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

        }

    }

    private byte[] readInFile(String path) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        byte[] data = null;
        File file = new File(path);
        InputStream input_stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                file));
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        data = new byte[16384]; // 16K
        int bytes_read;
        while ((bytes_read = input_stream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
            buffer.write(data, 0, bytes_read);
        }
        input_stream.close();
        return buffer.toByteArray();

    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;
```

**in the code**

```
  Button buttonLoadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPictureSelect);
    buttonLoadImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            imageIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            imageIntent.setType("image/*");
            imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(imageIntent , READ_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

} 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = null;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
                showImage(uri);
            }
        }
    }

    private void showImage(Uri uri) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
        imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("path_to_your_image".toString()));
    }
```

error:

```
The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (File)
```

in line

imageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("path_to_your_image".toString()));

**Update 2:**

```
private void showImage(Uri uri) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
       imageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/myimage.jpg")));
```

error:

```
The method setImageUri(Uri) is undefined for the type ImageView
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use Intent to search the image type files available in your device.

```
Intent imageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
imageIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
imageIntent.setType("image/*");
imageIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(imageIntent , READ_REQUEST_CODE); // set READ_REQUEST_CODE to 42 in your class
```

Now, process your results in the `onActivityResult()` method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        Uri uri = null;
        if (data != null) {
            uri = data.getData();
            Log.i(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            showImage(uri);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. Out of curiosity, where would I reference the imageview in the code ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicturePreview);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));/A

Comment: you can use the setImage(uri) method to show the image in the ImageView.

Comment: ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.parse(new File("path_to_your_image".toString()));

Comment: thank you again for your prompt response. I have encountered a minor error in eclipse "The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (File)". For your courteously, I have added an update section under my initial post. If you could kindly look into it i would appreciate

Comment: any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please use ImageView.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(your_file_path))); instead and check this resolves your issue 

also you must give the file path, like new File("/sdcard/myimage.jpg")

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63365/discussion-between-vembu-and-user3907211).

Comment: thank you so much from your prompt response..almost there. I have a concern, I have recieved an error for setImageUri - The method setImageUri(Uri) is undefined for the type ImageView, and out of curiosity what would be the neccesity of the line, as I do not want the user to grab a picture from a spefic location, nor I do I want to store it in my phone, just display it in imageivew.